# C# Parsing JSP webpage?

Tags: c#, html, web

How to parse this site?

It looks like HTML but actually, it is a java web page JSP.

[StockMarketSite](http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=0)

**Updated:** The data is loaded into the page by the Javascript. HTML Agility Pack only sees the page before the data is loaded so it cannot retrieve the data for you.

You can see this by going to the page then doing a View Page Source. The PSEi data isn't present in the HTML. It is only loaded later by the Javascript.

You need something that executes the Javascript on the page in order to get at the data.

http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=0

Needed to GET the PSEI data only. Been using HTML Agility Pack (But it is JSP file not HTML).

Here is my code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load("http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=0"));

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"ext - gen311\"]//div//table//tr//td//div//a");

var innertext = nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);
```

It Returns me:

```
Cannot load a null value.
```

Document Node:

```html
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="pseCorporateGovernance.html?ref=guidelines">Guidelines for Listed Companies</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="pseCorporateGovernance.html?ref=bellAwards">The PSE Bell Awards</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="pseCorporateGovernance.html?ref=scoreCard">ASEAN CG Scorecard</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/corporate/corporateGovernance.html?tab=0">Corporate Governance at PSE</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
  
<div id="newsNAnn" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="pressRoom.html">Press Room</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="circulars.html">PSE Circulars</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="announcements.html">Announcements</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="marketInfo" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <div id="marketInfo-marketActivity" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=0">Composite &amp; Sector Indices</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=1">Indices Composition</a></li>
    <!--li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=2">Charts</a></li-->
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=2">Most Active</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=3">Advances/Declines</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=4">Market Reports</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=5">Index History</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="marketInfo-globalMarkets" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html?tab=0">Market Indices</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html?tab=1">FTSE ASEAN Indices</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html?tab=2">Historical Index</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html?tab=3">Foreign Quotations</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html?tab=4">Currency Rates</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="fundsView.html?method=getFundView">Funds</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="content.html?sec=MARKET_WATCH_CONTENTS">Weekly Market Watch</a></li>
<!--  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="marketInfo-shortsell.html?method=viewShortsell">Shortsell Reports</a></li> -->
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="listNDisc" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="listedCompanyDirectory.html">Listed Company Directory</a></li>
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="companyInfo.html?tab=0">Company Information</a></li-->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="newListingsIpo.html">New Listings/IPO</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="disclosures.html">Corporate Disclosures</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="dividendRights.html">Dividends/Rights</a></li>
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="watchList.html">Watchlist</a></li-->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="changeCorporateNameMain.html">Change in Corporate Name/Delisted</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="prodNServices" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <div id="prodNServices-ETF" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=0">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=1">FAQs</a></li>
     <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=2">List of ETFs</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=3">Downloads</a></li>
<!--     <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=4">Related Links</a></li> -->
     <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=4">Market Makers</a></li>
<!--     <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=5">ETF Training Schedule</a></li> -->
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="prodNServices-Shariah" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="shariah.html?tab=0">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="shariah.html?tab=1">Methodology</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="shariah.html?tab=2">Shariah Compliant Securities</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="shariah.html?tab=3">Downloads</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="dollarDenominatedSecurities-dds" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="dollarDenominatedSecurities.html?tab=0">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="dollarDenominatedSecurities.html?tab=1">Rules</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="dollarDenominatedSecurities.html?tab=2">Presentations</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>


<!--
  <div id="prodNServices-Shortsell" class="x-hidden">
   <ul class="sideMenuMain">
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketDataProducts-shortsell.html?tab=0">Overview</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketDataProducts-shortsell.html?tab=1">Rules</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem"><a href="marketDataProducts-shortsell.html?tab=2">Q & A</a></li>
    <li class="sideMenuSubItem" style="border-bottom:0px"><a href="marketDataProducts-shortsell.html?tab=3">Eligible Security</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
-->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/SBL" target="_blank">Securities Borrowing and Lending</a></li>
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/portfolio/index.jsp" target="_blank">My Portfolio</a></li-->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/REIT" target="_blank">Real Estate Investment Trust</a></li>
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="myPortfolio.html?tab=0">My Portfolio</a></li>-->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="marketDataProducts.html?tab=0">Data Products</a></li>
<!--  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="marketDataProducts-shortsell.html">Shortsell</a></li> -->
<!-- <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="tradingProducts.html?tab=0">Trading Products</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="pseBusinessCentre.html?tab=0">PSE Business Centre</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="underConstruction.html">E-Wallet</a></li-->
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="onlineSys" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="https://csd.sccp.com.ph" target="_blank">SCCP - CSD</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="https://cch.sccp.com.ph" target="_blank">SCCP - CCH</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="https://www.pse.ph" target="_blank">iPSE</a></li>
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="https://odisy.pse.ph/j2ee/odisy/index.jsp" target="_blank">ODiSy</a></li-->
  <!--<li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="http://www.pse.ph/html/STG/index.html" target="_blank">Stock Trading Games</a></li>-->
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="http://www.pse.ph/sbl/index.html" target="_blank">Security Lending Program</a></li-->
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/nts/index.htm" target="_blank">PSETrade Update Website </a></li> -->
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/xts/index.htm" target="_blank">PSETrade Update Website </a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="/PSETradex" target="_blank">PSETradex </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="pseRulesNReg" class="x-hidden">
 <ul class="sideMenuMain">
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="listedCompaniesRules.html?tab=0">Listed Companies</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="tradingParticipantRules.html?tab=0">Trading Participants</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="tradingProductsRules.html?tab=0">Trading Products</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="amla.html?tab=0">Anti-Money Laundering</a></li>
  <li class="sideMenuItem" style="border-bottom:#591422 solid 1px "><a href="indexRules.html?tab=0">Index</a></li>
<!--  <li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="publicRules.html">Public</a></li>-->
  <!-- li class="sideMenuItem"><a href="underConstruction.html">Clearing and Settlement</a></li-->
 </ul>
</div>
<!--<div id="aseanLogo" class="x-hide-display" ><a href="http://www.aseanexchanges.com" target="_blank"><img src="/styles/pse/images/aseanExchangesLogo177.jpg"/></a></div>-->

<script type="text/javascript">
var internalSideMenu = new Ext.Panel({
     region: 'center',
     layout:'accordion',
     border: false,
     //activeItem: 1,
     defaults: {
         // applied to each contained panel
  
     },
     layoutConfig: {
         // layout-specific configs go here
         hideCollapseTool: false,
         titleCollapse: false,
         animate: true
     },
     items: [{
         title: 'About PSE',
         hideCollapseTool: true,
         titleCollapse: true,
         collapsed:true,
         listeners: {
          'beforeexpand' : {
           fn: function() {
//            window.location = '/stockMarket/home.html';
            window.open('/corporate/home.html?tab=0');
            return false;
           }
          }
         }
     },{
         title: 'Governance',
         titleCollapse: true,
         collapsed:true,
   //
         contentEl: 'governanceTab-Main',
         autoHeight:true,
   cls:'accordion-link',
         items: [{
          xtype: 'panel',
          layout:'accordion',
          border: false,
//       cls:'no-background-image',
       defaults: {
           // applied to each contained panel
           bodyStyle: 'padding:5px; background-color: #FFFEFF; border:1px solid #591422;',
           cls:'no-background-image'
       },
       layoutConfig: {
           // layout-specific configs go here
           hideCollapseTool: false,
           titleCollapse: false,
           animate: true
       },
       items: [{
           title: '<a style= "color: #444444">Market Governance</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           collapsed:false,
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'governanceTab'
       }]
         }]
     },{
      id: 'newsNAnn',
         title: 'News & Announcements',
         titleCollapse: true,
         contentEl: 'newsNAnn',
         collapsed:true,
         //
         autoHeight:true,
   cls:'accordion-link'
     },{
         title: 'Market Information',
         titleCollapse: true,
   collapsed:true,
         //
         collapsed:false,
         //
         contentEl: 'marketInfo',
   cls:'accordion-link',
         autoHeight:true,
         items: [{
          xtype: 'panel',
          layout:'accordion',
          border: false,
//       cls:'no-background-image',
       defaults: {
           // applied to each contained panel
           bodyStyle: 'padding:5px; background-color: #FFFEFF; border:1px solid #591422;',
           cls:'no-background-image'
       },
       layoutConfig: {
           // layout-specific configs go here
           hideCollapseTool: false,
           titleCollapse: false,
           animate: true
       },
       items: [{
           title: '<a href="marketInfo-marketActivity.html?tab=0" style= "color: #444444">Market Activity</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           //
           collapsed:false,
           //
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'marketInfo-marketActivity'
       },{
           title: '<a href="marketInfo-globalMarkets.html" style= "color: #444444">Global Markets</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           //
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'marketInfo-globalMarkets'
       }]
         }]
     },{
         title: 'Listings & Disclosures',
         titleCollapse: true,
         collapsed:true,
         //
         contentEl: 'listNDisc',
         autoHeight:true,
   cls:'accordion-link'
     }
  ,{
         title: 'Products & Services',
         titleCollapse: true,
         collapsed:true,
   //
         contentEl: 'prodNServices',
         autoHeight:true,
   cls:'accordion-link',
         items: [{
          xtype: 'panel',
          layout:'accordion',
          border: false,
//       cls:'no-background-image',
       defaults: {
           // applied to each contained panel
           bodyStyle: 'padding:5px; background-color: #FFFEFF; border:1px solid #591422;',
           cls:'no-background-image'
       },
       layoutConfig: {
           // layout-specific configs go here
           hideCollapseTool: false,
           titleCollapse: false,
           animate: true
       },
       items: [{
           title: '<a href="exchangeTradedFund.html?tab=0" style= "color: #444444">Exchange Traded Fund</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           //
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'prodNServices-ETF'
       },{
           title: '<a href="shariah.html?tab=0" style= "color: #444444">Shariah</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           //collapsed:false,
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'prodNServices-Shariah'
       },{
           title: '<a href="dollarDenominatedSecurities.html?tab=0" style= "color: #444444">Dollar Denominated Securities</a>',
           titleCollapse: true,
     collapsed:true,
           //collapsed:false,
           autoWidth: true,
           autoHeight: true,
           contentEl: 'dollarDenominatedSecurities-dds'
          }]
         }]
     }

               { xtype:'label', 
        html:'<br/>'
       },
       { 
        xtype: 'pseCalendar'
       },
    /*   //{
             //  xtype:'panel',
       //  border: false,
             //  id: 'bullrunPoster_logos',
                //    name: 'bullrunPoster_logos',
                //   html: '<a href="/resource/memos/2015/MEA_2015-0010.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/staticcontent/images/Bull Run 2015 Official Poster.png" align="top" width="100%"/></a><br>'
       //},*/
       {
           xtype:'panel',
        border: false,
              id: 'subsidiaryPoster',
                    name: 'subsidiaryPoster',
                    html: '<img src="/resource/subsidiary-icon.jpg" align="top" width="100%"/>'
       },
       { xtype:'label', 
        html:'<br/>'
       },
       {
           xtype:'panel',
        border: false,
              id: 'subsidiaryPoster_logos',
                    name: 'subsidiaryPoster_logos',
                    html: '<a href="http://www.sccp.com.ph" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/sccp-homeicon.jpg" align="top" width="50%"/></a><a href="http://www.cmic.com.ph" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/cmic-homeicon.jpg" align="top" width="50%"/></a>'
       }
       ,{
           xtype:'panel',
        border: false,
              id: 'infographics',
                   name: 'infographics',
                   html: '<a href="/resource/2Q17_v4.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/2Q17_v4.PNG" align="top" width="100%"/><br><br>'
       }

       ,{
           xtype:'panel',
        border: false,
              id: 'futsal',
                 name: 'futsal',
                html: '<a href="/resource/stockmarketinvestorprofile/Stock_Market_Investor_Profile_2016_final.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/stockmarketinvestorprofile/file/SMIP_2016.PNG" align="top" width="100%"/><br><br>'
       }
/*
       ,{
              xtype:'panel',
        border: false,
              id: 'bellAwards',
                   name: 'bellAwards',
                    html: '<a href="/corporate/bellAwards.html?yr=2015" target="_blank"><img src="/resource/bellAwards/images/2015 Bell Awards Banner design-PSE web-academy.jpg" align="top" width="100%"/><br><br>'
       }
*/

      ]
          }
  ]
 });
 
 function showProfile(profile, name) {
  if(profile == ''){
   profile = '<i>Not available.</i>'
  }
  var profileWindow = new Ext.Window({
   title: name,
   width: 550,
   height: 934,
   scrollable: true,
   layout: 'fit',
   items: [{
     xtype: 'panel',
     border: false,
     bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px;text-align:justify',
     html: '<center><img src="'+profile+'" width="500px"/></center>'
     }],
   modal: true
  });
  profileWindow.show();
 }
</script>


<style type="text/css">
 /*
  * indices tab style override
  */
  .x-grid3-header-offset {width:100% !important;}
  .x-grid3-header-inner {width:100% !important;} 
 .x-grid3-row {width:100% !important;}
 .x-grid3 table {
     width: 100% !important;
 }
 span.x-tab-strip-inner  {
  padding-top:2px;
  padding-right:8px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  padding-left:0px;
 }
 .x-grid3-row-table {
  padding-bottom:4px;
 }

</style>

<div id='border-panel' style="padding:0px;margin:5px">
<div id='navbar'><h6><a href="home.html">Home</a> / <a href="#">Market Info</a> / Market Activity</h6></div>
</div>

<div id="middleColumnCom">
<div id='marketActivityDetails'>

As of July 24, 2017 03:20:00 PM

</div>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function(){
 Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var p = new Ext.Panel({
     layout:'column',
     border: false,
  autoHeight: true,
     bodyBorder: false,
     width: 950,
     defaults: {
   collapsible: false,
         split: false,
   animFloat: false,
   autoHide: false
  },
     items: [{
      autoHeight: true,
         columnWidth: 0.2,
      border: false,
      bodyBorder: false,
      style: 'margin: 0 10px 0 0',
      items: [sideMenu]
     },{
      autoHeight: true,
         columnWidth: 0.8,
      border: false,
      bodyBorder: false,
      bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px',
    contentEl: 'middleColumnCom'  
     }],
  renderTo: 'border-panel'
 });
 
 var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
  //
  activeTab : '0',
  //
  // 
     height: 600,
  autoHeight: true,
  plain:true,
     items:[{
      autoHeight: true,
      title:'Composite &amp; Sector Indices',
   autoLoad: {
          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-compositesAndSectorIndices.html?ajax=true&method=viewCompositesAndSectorIndices',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
     },{ 
      autoHeight: true,
      title:'Indices Composition',
   autoLoad: {
    url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-indicesComposition.html?method=viewIndicesComposition',
    params: '&ajax=true&indexName=',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
     }
//disabled: feature not yet available
//  ,{
//      autoHeight: true,
//      title:'Charts',
//   autoLoad: {
//          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-charts.html?ajax=true',
//          method: 'GET', 
//          scripts: true
//         }
//     }
  ,{ 
      autoHeight: true,
      title:'Most Active',
   autoLoad: {
          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-mostActive.html?ajax=true',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
     },{
      autoHeight: true,
         title:'Advances/Declines',
   autoLoad: {
          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-advancesDeclines.html?ajax=true',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
        },{
         autoHeight: true,
         title:'Market Reports',
   autoLoad: {
          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-marketReports.html?ajax=true&method=viewMarketReports',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
        },{
         autoHeight: true,
         title:'Index History',
   autoLoad: {
          url: 'marketInfo-marketActivity-historicalData.html?ajax=true&method=viewIndexHistory',
    params: 'ajax=true&sector=ALL',
          method: 'GET', 
          scripts: true
         }
        }],
     renderTo: 'marketActivityDetails'
 });
});

</script>


            </div>
```

Comment: The given URL simply returns HTML content. Whether this was created by JSP, ASP, PHP, or whatever technology is irrelevant for the result.

Comment: Does nodes collection returned by doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes has any node in it?

Comment: Debug steps: did you get a document? Inspect that doc by hand: do you see that id? Try and select the node with that id - do you get it? Add extra elements to the path (maybe using single slashes): does it exist in the html? Can you select it?

Comment: tried using single slashes but no luck. Maybe I am calling in HTML form instead of JSP?

Comment: JSP is a server side technology, just like ASP.Net. The result of both is plain html.

Comment: Do a "view source" of that page you are expecting, then try and find that id. This source is exactly what your code sees and I couldn't find that id in there. So neither can your code.

Comment: @HansKesting updated the post, with Document Node data

Comment: Please locate "ext - gen311" or even "gen311" anywhere in that source. Note that using "Load" does *not* execute any javascript code!

Comment: @HansKesting the problem is the 'ext gen311' is not there. I saw in VS breakpoint, the table was not loaded.

Comment: @PankajKapare updated the post. The "ext gen311" table was not loaded in html agility pack

Comment: @HansKesting I have updated the post. The data is loaded into the page by the Javascript. HTML Agility Pack only sees the page before the data is loaded so it cannot retrieve the data for you.

Comment: The page makes several AJAX requests. Are you looking for the data [from this](http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/dailySummary.html?method=getMarketIndices&ajax=true&_dc=1500954871550)? Looks like you need a JSON parser instead.

Comment: @canon can you point me where should I start in JSON parsing?

Comment: @user122289 http://json.org

Comment: @canon I'm starting to get it... but one question... the website has a security code changing every minute http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/dailySummary.html?method=getMarketIndices&ajax=true&_dc=1500954871550 the number dc is random: 1500954871550 How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score -1):

This is a sledgehammer approach, but still for me the most reliable. For your question, you can use a tool recognition(lexer/parser) for that language, there are a bunch out there: ANTLR, YACC, DMS, ... 
Just you need to download the grammar and generate the lexer and the parser, then you can process the text that should comply with the rules of the grammar/language. Here is a list of the grammars you can find for ANTLR: [grammar list](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).
At that point, you obtain and [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and from there you can iterate over the nodes of your language.

Comment: is there a c# sample to grammar list?

Comment: @user122289 to obtain the c# grammar you mean?

Comment: yes. but the data is loaded into the page by the Javascript. HTML Agility Pack only sees the page before the data is loaded so it cannot retrieve the data for you.

Comment: @user122289 let me tell you, this is the C# grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp but it is to recognize text that belongs to that grammar, you should look for the jsp grammar, then load the text of the HTML, let's say with a request to the page and then pass the text to the grammar and load the AST. After that point, you should be able to have all the elements, but if you can't get the HTML loaded with all elements, then you are still facing the same problem that you have with the HTML Agility Pack